# How to use NCC (nccgen/nccnav)?

Tags: gcc, call-graph, program-flow

I'd like to understand how to use a tool called NCC:
http://students.ceid.upatras.gr/~sxanth/ncc/

Its purpose is to detail program call graph and internal symbol dependencies, similar to cflow/cscope. But I can't get it to work.

I've cloned a git repo of tcpdump project and edited Makefile `CC` to point to `nccgen -ncgcc -ncld -ncfabs` instead of `CC = gcc`

Here's the output:

`` make[1]: Entering directory `/home/rostamn739/Software/tcpdump' ``

`` make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'. ``

`` make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rostamn739/Software/tcpdump' ``

No `.nccout` files have been produced

Comment: Have you tested with other projects than tcpdump? Do you get the expected result if you run ncc on a simple hello world file?